# Angular @Input of type Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Is it bad practice to pass in a component's @Input an observable ?

For example:
The template of the parent will have

```
<profile-edit [items$]="profileFacade.items$">
```

and the ProfileEditComponent will have a variable like this:

```
@Input items$: Observable<ProfileItem[]>
```

And use the | async pipe to unrwap the values of the observable in the template
of the ProfileEditComponent

Comment: Thanks @Tomas. Edited...

Comment: Be care with Observables as @Input, as they trigger ngOnChanges a lot. Use with care

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not good practice. Angular provides you an `async` pipe which is exactly what you want here.

When using `async` pipe:

- less code is generated since you do not need to subscribe to the observable first.
- The component does not need to know about `Observable` class and is more stupid like this

So  I think this:

```
<profile-edit [items]="profileFacade.items$ | async">


@Input items: ProfileItem[]
```

Is cleaner and better than this:

```
<profile-edit [items]="profileFacade.items$">`


@Input items: Observable<ProfileItem[]>`
```

Just my guesses, I am not a specialist.

Comment: I disagree. Observable input is not bad practice. Moreover, It allows to set the changeDetectionStrattegy to OnPush, which will result in an optimized component, and no OnChanges interface has to be implemented to handle changes.

Answer (score 4):

For `async` pipe this is good solution, but be aware of change detection mechanism. Because from angular point of view `[items]` bounded property does not change, if your change detection strategy will be set to `onPush`, your view might not be refreshed accordingly. Then, you will need to manually subscribe to this input observable and on each change trigger change detection by yourself.